# jquery :last missing multiple classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an unordered list, and am using jquery to find the last ul and apply a class.

```
jQuery("ul.class1:last").addClass("lastUi");
```

The html is as follows:

```
<ul class="class1"></ul>
<ul class="class1"></ul>
```

This is working fine, however it has now changed in that another class is being added to the list so the html looks like:

```
<ul class="class1"></ul>
<ul class="class1 class2"></ul>
<ul class="class1"></ul>
<ul class="class1 class2"></ul>
```

The jQuery code is now not picking up the last ul with both class1 and class2 as the last element and isn't adding the lastUI class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>$("ul.class1, ul.class2").filter(":last").addClass("lastUi");</strike>

The above one will select last element even if it has only class 2.

Hope this works fine for you

```
$("ul[class~=class1]:last").addClass("lastUi");
```

Comment: It does work fine. Problem was that there are two separate lists, and it was applying to the end as set. Just need to select based on list type.